# Design images, buttons, text, etc to fit all screen sizes for android tablet in landscape mode

Tags: android, screen

I am a bit confused about resolution of Android Tablets. Each Tablet has different resolution and size. How can I design images, logos, buttons, etc to fit all android Tablet size in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the images for only one size (or for one device).
Lets say you are working on a tablet with screen size 640x960.
You can then make a layer of size 640x960 and add the images to that layer.
Once you have your layer with all the images you want on it, you must then scale that layer up or down depending on the device screen.

So if you made an image for a device with screen pixels: 640 x 960, and you test it on a different device with screen size 400 x 800, you would then scale the layer that contains your images like so:

`layer->setScaleX(640/400);`
`layer->setScaleY(960/800);`

And the layer will stretch inwards to fit the smaller screen.

Comment: everytime we need to make resize for depends on device size. But it is not good thing. Only single application work for all android versions as well as work for all size. Once I test with one device with related size. It should work for other device with different size. No need to resize everytime depends on device size. I am not clear with your answer

Comment: i am sure can get the device's screen size by calling some function. Once you have the device screen size, you can do:                `float deviceWidth = getWidthFunction;                           float deviceHeight = getHeightFunction;` and then you do: `layer->setScaleX(640/deviceWidth); layer->setScaleY(960/deviceHeight);`

Comment: No problem, in the mean time would you please up vote this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: how can we create the layer? is there any tutorial to follow?

Comment: You can use an engine like Cocos2dX, I use Cocos2dX for my layers and images and other stuff